# Embed Listview into Preferences in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-preferences

I need to show a list in Preferences view, so I created my own class (inherit of `Preference`) and then set it like this:

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent){

    cards = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Test
    cards.add("4859-2368957415");
    cards.add("4859-5987412598");

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext()); 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

    list = new ListView(getContext()); 
    list.setLayoutParams(params); 
    layout.addView(list); 
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cards); 
    list.setAdapter(adapter); 
    return layout; 
}
```

This works, but I can't scroll it (it shows really tiny). I think that my Listview is embed into a Preference (with its own width and height by default), but I need to show a completely list.

How can I achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: A preference screen is a `ListView`. You cannot successfully embed a `ListView` in a `ListView`. Most likely, you will want to create your own layout for your `PreferenceActivity`, one which has your own separate `ListView` below the first one, splitting the screen. Or, stick with the standard `ListPreference`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem adding `PreferenceScreen` dynamically instead of embedding a `ListView` component into a `Preference`.

```
findPreference("addmyaccount").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        // Get preference category and add a custom preference (simulating a ListView)
        PreferenceCategory targetCategory = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("myaccounts");
        final Preference account = new Preference(Settings.this);

        account.setKey("mykey");

        account.setTitle("Custom Preference");

        targetCategory.addPreference(account);
        editor.putString("mykey", "Custom Preference");
        editor.commit();

    }
});
```