# How to create dynamic listView in Preferences like in Wifi (or bluetooth) settings?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to create dynamic `ListView` in preferences, like in Android settings (Wi-Fi networks available). I don't want opening new dialog. Is this possible for API 8+?

Comment: Have you figured out the answer? I'm struggling with the same issue...

Comment: how about using custom preference through extend Preference? see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947539/embed-listview-into-preferences-in-android)